# Xcode15 packaging, translucent icon changes in xcassets

Tags: assets, xcode15

Using Xcode 15 for packaging, the translucent icon in Assets.car in ipa is quite different from the icon in the actual project, resulting in a discrepancy between the effect and the design and failing to meet the design requirements.

I hope that the translucent icon packaged by Xcode15 can look the same as the original icon.